# MASM32 error when I use call DumpRegs

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

So I have looked around the site and have not found a solution to my problem. I tried adding the following lines that was the answer for someone else's question but it did not work for me.

```
includelib C:\full\path\to\Kernel32.Lib
includelib C:\full\path\to\User32.Lib
includelib C:\full\path\to\Irvine32.lib

; include C:\full\path\to\Irvine32.inc
```

Here is my entire code.

```
includelib C:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc
includelib C:\Irvine\Kernel32.Lib
includelib C:\Irvine\User32.Lib
includelib C:\Irvine\Irvine32.lib

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword



.data
    num BYTE 126d
    num2 SBYTE -26d
    num3 WORD   692Ah
    num4 SWORD -32789
    num5 DWORD 12345678h
    num6 SDWORD -2147483648

.code
main proc
    mov al, num
    call DumpRegs   ; I get the error when I put this in.

    mov ah, num2
    mov cx, num3
    mov dx, num4
    mov eax, num5
    mov ebx, num6


    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

And here is the output that I get.

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
>   1>  Assembling ..\ch03\AddTwo.asm...
>   1>..\ch03\AddTwo.asm(25): error A2006: undefined symbol : dumpRegs
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(50,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml.exe /c /nologo /Sg /WX /Zi /Fo"Debug\AddTwo.obj" /Fl"Project.lst" /I "c:\Irvine" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta..\ch03\AddTwo.asm" exited with code 1.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Make sure you got the case right, `DumpRegs` is not the same as `dumpRegs`. Also `Irive32.inc` is not `Irvine32.inc`.

Comment: I made the changes and it still does not compile. What now?

Comment: The `Irvine32.inc` should be `include` not `includelib`.

Comment: @Jester I commented out `call DumpRegs` and it compiled with `includelib C:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc` and it compiled. When I just put `include` like you said it gives a compile error. I think I'll just comment that out for now or do I really need it?

Comment: It compiles because the assembler silently ignores it and you don't use anything else from there. It should be `include`. Also the [manual says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy42f858.aspx) both of those **must be enclosed in angle brackets if it includes a backslash**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My professor told me to delete some of the code so this is what I am left with

```
TITLE Add and Subtract          (AddSub.asm)

; This program adds and subtracts 32-bit integers.

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
    num BYTE 126d
    num2 SBYTE -26d
    num3 WORD   692Ah
    num4 SWORD -32789
    num5 DWORD 12345678h
    num6 SDWORD -2147483648

.code
main PROC

    mov al, num
    call DumpRegs

    mov ah, num2
    mov cx, num3
    mov dx, num4
    mov eax, num5
    mov ebx, num6

    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

and my code works.

He told me not to use

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword
```

at the beginning of our programs. or the

```
invoke ExitProcess,0
```

at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you are not including sufficient libraries or correct libraries !
error in your include lines.

> ;includelib C:\masm615\Irvine\Irvine32.inc;
>   ;includelib C:\masm615\Irvine\Kernel32.Lib;
>   ;includelib C:\masm615\Irvine\User32.Lib;
>   ;includelib C:\masm615\Irvine\Irvine32.lib;
>   Include irvine32.inc ;this will include them all;
>   .386;
>   .model flat,stdcall;
>   .stack 4096
>   ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword;
>   ;
>   .data      ;
>       num BYTE 126d;
>       num2 SBYTE -26d;
>       num3 WORD   692Ah;
>       num4 SWORD -32789;
>       num5 DWORD 12345678h;
>       num6 SDWORD -2147483648;
>   ;
>   .code;
>   main proc;
>       mov al, num;
>       call DumpRegs   ; I get the error when I put this in.;
>       mov ah, num2;
>       mov cx, num3;
>       mov dx, num4;
>       mov eax, num5;
>       mov ebx, num6;
>   ;
>       invoke ExitProcess,0;
>   main endp;
>   end main;